# Why does this throw java.nio.file.InvalidPathException?

Tags: java, swing, directory

The program throws

```
 Exception in thread "main" java.nio.file.InvalidPathException: Illegal char 
  <:> at index 2: ‪E:\New folder
      at sun.nio.fs.WindowsPathParser.normalize(WindowsPathParser.java:182)
      at sun.nio.fs.WindowsPathParser.parse(WindowsPathParser.java:153)
      at sun.nio.fs.WindowsPathParser.parse(WindowsPathParser.java:77)
      at sun.nio.fs.WindowsPath.parse(WindowsPath.java:94)
      at sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileSystem.getPath(WindowsFileSystem.java:255)
      at java.nio.file.Paths.get(Paths.java:84)
      at 
 javaapplication10.ACDirectoryListenerServiceImpl.main(ACDirectoryListenerServiceImpl.java:93)
Java Result: 1
```

When I try to get a path of a file with

```
Path path = Paths.get("‪E:\\New folder");
```

why is that? Are drive letters allowed when getting paths?

Comment: Error say: ``Illegal char 
  <:> at index 2: ‪E:\New folder``

Comment: Drive letters are definitely allowed, really weird `Exception`… Shouldn't it point to `index 1` if the colon is what it wants to point to?

Comment: Im seeing documentation and see you are converting a URI to a path, what happen ? Here a small answer ``IllegalArgumentException - if preconditions on the uri parameter do not hold. The format of the URI is provider specific.``

Comment: Have you tried the first method: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Paths.html#get(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String...) ``get(String first, String... more)``

Comment: I'll try that one ^^. This is really weird. It doesn't work either if I test 'Path path = new File("E:\\New Folder").toPath();' either. I've seen people do this without any problems.

Comment: @Naldery Im using **Netbeans IDE 8.2** and works perfectly.

Comment: @Naldery try this: ``Path ruta = Paths.get("E:","ftpaqui","archivotransf.txt");
        System.out.println(ruta);``

Comment: @Naldery Can i add the answer and you put how correct answer ?

Comment: @deon of course. I am new to Stackoverflow, so pardon me

Comment: Check to make sure `"E:\\New Folder"` contains the characters you think it does. Not sure if it's an issue with this site or I'm making a mistake, but when I copy your string and print it out to console (a simple `System.out.println`) I get `?E:\New Folder`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The „:“ is „at index 2“, that is the *third* character of the string. The drive letter should be at index 0, and the „:“ should be at index 1.

**There is a zero-width character in your string.** You can find the character by moving the cursor letter by letter with the arrow keys. The character is where the cursor seems not to react to the keypress.

I see this happening when I copy a file path from Windows’ “file properties” dialog, security page, „object name“, when I select the path with the mouse *from end to beginning*, there is a non-printing unicode “left-to-right embedding” character (U+202A) before the drive letter. It is not visible even with <kbd>¶</kbd> enabled (I tried Notepad++ and Eclipse). This does not happen when I select the path from beginning to end.

Credit to [Slaw](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6395627) who pointed in the right direction in his comment.